# Mountpoints, file permissions

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions, files, fstab

I have an application that writes to `/var/lib/yacy`.  I have a partition I want to use for that database.  I have the partition mounted in `fstab` at `/home/somwhere/partition`

I want to move the current contents of the `/var/lib/yacy` into the mounted partition then change the `fstab` to point that device to `/var/lib/yacy`.  How do I do this maintaining permissions and not breaking anything?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going about this in such a roundabout way, you could just use `/var/lib/yacy` as the mount point for your partition instead. Edit your fstab file to mount the filesysytem on that mounpoint.
As for setting appropriate permissions check out this page http://www.linuxstall.com/fstab/.
You will need to reboot your computer for the changes to come into effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're /var/lib/yacy partition is a LVM logical volume then why not just extend the size if space is the concern?

You can read more about LVM here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm

`$ pvdisplay # display all available Physical Disks`

`$ vgdisplay # display available volume groups`

`$ lvdisplay # display all logical volumes`

The easiest way to increase the size of your logical volume is to first increase the size of the VolumeGroup where the logical volume belongs.

Example
`$ sudo vgextend VolumeGroupName /home/somwhere/partition # Extend the size of the volume group to /home/somwhere/partition`

Once you got your volume group extended, you can re-size the logical volume of interest
`$ sudo lvextend -L +10g /var/lib/yacy # This will add 10GB to /var/lib/yacy`

Reboot for the kernel to recognize the logical volume increase or use resize2fs command to resize logical volume on the fly.